# How do I determine the energy of a wavefunction after computing a numerical solution?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics

I am working on a simple example of how to numerically solve the time-independent Schrodinger Equation for the infinite square well. I've used the Euler Method to find values of the wave function, $\psi (x)$, but now I've just realized something - I have no clue how to determine the energies from this! I know that analytically this comes down to applying the Hamiltonian to the wavefunction, but how do I find the energies numerically??

I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170546/25301

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numerical solution to Schrödinger equation - eigenvalues](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/170546/)

Answer (score 0):

Compute
$$E = \int dx \psi^*(x)\left(\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 + V(x)\right)\psi(x) $$

Comment: Would this be done with Monte Carlo integration? Or what method of integration should I use?

Comment: If you have the wavefunction explicitly as a function of x, you should be able to perform the integration directly (i.e., using quadrature methods). Monte Carlo is not really recommended for a one-dimensional integral (although if you had, say, a large spin system, that'd be a different story). Your main problem is going to be numerical differentiation, which is always kind of a pain.

Comment: I have $x$ values and $\psi (x)$ values. Is that what I need to use a quadrature method?

Comment: You need second derivatives (including mixed ones) of phi as well. I tried to do numerical differentiation by just applying the limit definition recently, unfortunately the finite precision will make the derivative zero if you go too far in the limit so it can be tricky to choose an appropriate value for it!

Comment: Oh! I have second derivatives as well!

Comment: @Emil The OP could get away with computing only first derivatives as $\psi(x)^* \, \partial_x^2 \psi(x)$ partially integrates to $\bigl | \partial_x \psi(x) \bigr |^2$.

Comment: @Max Lein: good catch. Not sure if it is 1d or nd though. I am fuzzy on how to compute normals from a nonorthogonal basis which would be needed in nd if I recall the formula correct.

Answer (score 0):

For a lot of the questions if you simply want to know about the fundamental energy of the system you don't even have to solve the Schrödinger Equations. Just simple dimensional analysis will tell you the order of the energy of the system. It is much much quicker and you will get a very good intuitive understanding of the system. With Dimensional Analysis, you can construct energies with simple factors like $\bar h$ and $f$. This is much easier than trying to solve the SE for complicated systems.